# How to test my viewModel that is Koin injected?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, koin

I have a ViewModel. It calls a funtion in my data repo and gets back a list of the dog object.

```
class MainViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val dataRepo: DataRepo by inject(DataRepo::class.java) //dataRepo
    private var limit = 10
    private val _dogListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Dog>>()
    private var dogList = mutableListOf<Dog>()

    val dogListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Dog>>
        get() = _dogListLiveData

    fun searchByBreed(queryText: String) {
        dataRepo.searchByBreed(
            queryText,
            object : DataSource.OnResponseCallback<List<Dog>, String> {
                override fun onSuccess(obj: List<Dog>?) {
                    dogList = mutableListOf()
                    if(!obj.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    dogList.addAll(obj)
                    dogListLiveData.value = dogList.take(limit)
                    }

                }

                override fun onError(error: String) {
                    Log.i("Calling Network Service", error)
                }
            })

    }

    fun loadPaginateBreed() : Boolean{
        return if ((limit+10) < dogList.size) {
            limit += 10
            Log.i("Pagination new Limit", limit.toString())
            dogListLiveData.value = dogList.take(limit)
            false
        }else{
            limit += dogList.size%limit
            dogListLiveData.value = dogList.take(limit)
            true
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write a simple unit test for it. I've written this and tried many other iterations. But nothing seems to work.

```
package com.example.koinapplication.ui.main

import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import com.example.koinapplication.custom.adpaters.GranularErrorCallAdapterFactory
import com.example.koinapplication.models.Dog
import com.example.koinapplication.models.Height
import com.example.koinapplication.models.Weight
import com.example.koinapplication.repo.*
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.dsl.viewModel
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.context.stopKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.inject
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations
import java.util.*

class MainViewModelTest {


    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by inject(MainViewModel::class.java)

    lateinit var obserserData : Observer<List<Dog>>

    private val networkModule = module {
        factory { AuthInterceptor() }
        factory { provideOkHttpClient(get()) }
        factory { GranularErrorCallAdapterFactory<Any>() }
        single { providesNetworkClient(get(), get()) }
        single { DataRepo(get()) }
        single { NetworkRepo(get()) }
    }


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        startKoin {
            modules(arrayListOf(networkModule))
        }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun searchByBreed() {
        mainViewModel.dogListLiveData.observeForever { obserserData }
        mainViewModel.searchByBreed("dal")
        Mockito.verify(obserserData).onChanged(mainViewModel.dogListLiveData.value)
    }
}
```

Please help me write a simple test to test the data in my viewModel. Help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice keeping all Dependency Injection (DI) Frameworks out of your ViewModel. This makes your ViewModel independent and simplifies your unit tests.

**ViewModel**

So instead of injecting your dependency in your ViewModel you can pass them via constructor:

```
class MainViewModel(
    private val dataRepo: dataRepo
) : ViewModel() {
    // ...
}
```

**Koin Module**

In your Koin module you can define the dependencies and provide an instance of your ViewModel:

```
module {
  single { DataRepo(get()) }
  factory { MainViewModel(dataRepo = get())}
}
```

In your Activity or Fragment you can then inject your ViewModel as usual.

**Unit Test**

In your `MainViewModelTest` you do not need any code for Koin:

```
class MainViewModelTest {
    private val dataRepo: DataRepo = mockk() // I used Mockk for mocking, but you can use any other mocking framework

    private val mainViewModel = MainViewModel(dataRepo) // your class under test

    @Test
    fun yourTest() {
        // prepare
        every { dataRepo.searchByBreed(...)} returns ...

        mainViewModel.searchByBreed(queryText = "...")

        // do assertions
    }
}
```

Having this, simplifies writing unit tests a lot. And you could exchange Koin with any other DI Framework later without the need touching your ViewModel and the test(s).

I hope this helps you a bit.